# Hangin IKEA ALGOT shelve on drywall-like structure

Tags: drywall, drywall-anchor, shelf

There is a 50 mm thick wall which separates my balcony from the neighbors one. The damage done accidentally by my neighbor, show structure similar to drywall

[image: Wall structure]

I was thinking about mounting an IKEA ALGOT using:

- Two [84 cm wall uprights](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/products/storage-furniture/storage-systems/algot-wall-upright-white-art-10218536/).
- One [88 cm mounting rail](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/products/storage-furniture/storage-systems/algot-mounting-rail-white-art-20236484/).
- Three 38 cm wide metal shelve.

Ideally I'd like to support up to 15 kilograms per shelf giving ~ 45 kg in total.

Now, wall uprights are mounted using 4 bolts. Since I cannot simply drill through the wall and use proper drywall anchors,  I was thinking about something like [30 mm Fischer Duo Power plastic fixings](https://www.fischer-international.com/en/products/standard-fixings/plastic-fixings/duopower/555006-duopower-6-x-30) (according to specs it should support at least 6 kg / bolt), but I have serious doubts if it can hold the load.

I'd be grateful for any insights / suggestions.

Comment: Do not know what " 30 mm Fischer Duo Power " is.

Comment: @Alaskaman Thanks for pointing this out. I've edited the question.